# PHP - Sessions don't work on Free Hosting

Tags: php, session

I've been working on a project and sessions work perfectly on localhost.

But I've signed up in a free hosting with domain like this: nameWrittenByMe.NameGivenByHost.es

**And I've tried everything but I don't get it to work**

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain',
substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."),100));

session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', '.a.b.es', false, false);
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', 'a.b.es', false, false);
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', 'b.es', false, false);
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', '.b.es', false, false);
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', '.b.es');
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', 'b.es');
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', '.a.b.es');
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', 'a.b.es');
```

and on .htacces i've tried

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .a.b.es
php_value session.cookie_domain a.b.es
php_value session.cookie_domain .b.es
php_value session.cookie_domain b.es
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible that a free hosting (I'm using Hostinger) doesn't support sessiones (i doubt it...)

Thanks.

Comment: Well, first of all the hoster and clarify if it is possible to use or not. Doubting or believing does not help you with troubleshooting here.

Comment: It's possible that with (free!!) hosting they don't let you modify php.ini settings (even temporarily), which is essentially what you're doing with `session_set_cookie_params()`.  As hakre said, before coming here you should check with hostinger.

Comment: Start by uploading a script containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, call it and look for the block named "session".  You can then add that info to the question.

Comment: @fvu i've done what you say, sessions are enabled
http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/6850/sinttuloqtl.png

Comment: @frankie4 well that already takes away your doubts re session support :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `.htaccess`:

```
php_flag output_buffering on
```